# Let $n \in \mathbb {Z}$. If $n^2$ is even, then $n$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I think that a proof by contrapositive can do, but I don't know how to complete it.

Assume that $n$ is odd. Then, $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$. Therefore, $n^2= (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2+4k+1$.

I know that now I should prove that $n^2$ is odd. I also know that even + even + odd = odd, but I was wondering if there is another way to prove it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For the record, your proof works fine.

Comment: From your work, $4k^2+4k+1=2(2k^2+2k)+1$, so has remainder $1$ upon division by $2$, so is odd.

Comment: You've done all the hard work. $(n^2$ even $\implies n$ even$)$ is equivalent to $(n$ odd $\implies n^2$ odd $)$ by the contrapositive. Since $4k^2+4k+1=2k(2k+2)+1$, you've shown that $n^2$ is odd provided $n$ is odd.

Comment: You can use prime factorization too for a "direct proof"; however, this is heavier machinery than you need.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm new at MSE and didn't realize there were comments here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write: $n^2= (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2+4k+1=2(2k^2+2k)+1=2m+1$, where $m=2k^2+2k.$ Since $k \in \mathbb {Z}$, we have $m \in \mathbb {Z}$. Thus, $n^2= 2m+1$ for some integer $m$. Hence, $n^2$ is an odd integer.

---

You can also use a proof by contradiction.

> Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $n^2$ is even and $n$ is odd.  Then, $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$. Thus, $n^2=(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1=2(2k^2+2k)+1=2m+1$, where $m=2k^2+2k$. Since $k \in \mathbb {Z}$, we have $m \in \mathbb {Z}$. Thus, $n^2= 2m+1$ for some integer $m$. Hence, $n^2$ is an odd integer. Contradiction. Therefore, we deduce that if $n^2$ is even, then $n$ is even.

Comment: And I'll try to work through the proof by contradiction without looking at yours ;)

Comment: *NB:* although I have seen it in quite a few places, this "proof by contradiction" seems an "absurd absurdum" is Conway's sense.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $n^2-n=n(n-1)$. Either $n$ or $n-1$ is even, and hence $n(n-1)$ is even. So, $n^2-n$ is even. But it's given that $n^2$ is even. So, $n$ must be even :).

Comment: Technically, the claim that one of $n$ and $n-1$ is even requires proof.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just show that $(n+1)n-n(n-1)=2n$ so, by induction $n^2-n$ is always even...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: yes :). But I am sure OP can prove that- as he has already done similar proof above.

Comment: Thank you voldemort and @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 3):

We can prove something more generic $$\text{odd}\cdot\text{odd}=\text{odd}\text{ and }\text{even}\cdot\text{(any integer)}=\text{even}$$

for if $\displaystyle a\equiv1\pmod2,b\equiv1\pmod2\implies a\cdot b\equiv1\cdot1\pmod2$

and if $a\equiv0\pmod2,b$ is any integer; $a\cdot b\equiv0\cdot b\pmod2\equiv0$

Comment: Good idea. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the proof you give is the most standard one but I do have another. It relies on the fact that for $p,a,b \in \mathbf{Z}$ with $p$ prime, $$p|ab \implies p|a \text{ or } p|b$$

Setting $p=2, \, a=b=n$ gives $$2|n^2=n \cdot n \implies 2|n \text{ or } 2|n \implies 2|n$$

The 'fact' I've given above is established formally in first-year undergraduate number theory courses and relies on a number of other theorems. This might raise concern about circularity, but I don't think that's an issue here.